# python machine learning DeprecationWarning

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, scikits

Please could you help me to solve this?

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44‌: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also, note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20. "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: Please [post text, not screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3005167), even if it is convenient for you :)

Comment: thank you,  this is the problem that I can't solve it       C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The

`C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44‌: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also, note that the interface of the new CV iterators is different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20. "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)`

is just a **deprecation warning**.

---

No need to worry but keep in mind that `cross_val` will be removed in `0.20`.

This error is just to warn you that the developers are going to move this function before they do it.

---

Just an example.In the future we will have to replace:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
```

with:

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
```

---

For the **second error** that I can see in the screenshot that you posted, the `SA3L module` seems not to be installed.

Comment: Thank you #Sera yes I know it is warning and I used warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") but still it is available but any way thanks I will ignore it  and yes regarding my error I think I did not import this class thank you

Comment: @javac In other words, they will put the classes that were under cross_validation into now model_selection.

Comment: yes that is right I just read about this issue in scikit learn website . thanks

Comment: @javac no problem. If this helped please mark it as acdepted answer. Also, I added a simple example in my answer

Comment: still is available even I tried this import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()

Comment: @javac Do not try to suppress the warning. 1) It is not bad 2) someone should be aware of such deprecations. But if you still want: try: import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

Comment: @javac Also make sure that along with the package name change, the internal structure of classes have also changed. I mean that KFold as worked in `cross_validation` may not work in `model_selection`, or have attributes and function names changed as well. Always consult the documentation for using.

Answer (score 1):

Now cross_validation has been deprecated and model_selection is used instead, However all the methods and classes remains the same. You just have to now import:

```
from sklearn import model_selection
```

and for training and testing the data you have to do something like this:

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=model_selection.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
```